# CHDK scripting: on topic?

Tags: support

Are CHDK scripting questions on topic here, and if not, where could I ask?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's programming, so you could ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) — there appear to be a [handful of CHDK questions already](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=chdk), although on closer look only one is actually really about CHDK itself.

I'd say they're on-topic as long as they're about scripting for the sake of photography. If you're trying to write a Pac-Man clone, I'd say not so much.

Comment: My questions will absolutely be about photography; will give forming the first one a go later today. Thank you.